# Add Android Source build jar library to Android Studio

Tags: android

I did tried many solution on Stackoverflow to include library in Android Studio.

I am trying to build the jar file in android source.
I have my source copied to /device/company_name/Device_name/Amol/framework/java/com/symbol/amol/Amol.java
After build completes. I see the com.symbol.amol.jar is created in /system/framework/.

Now, to try this jar file, I have created a Android application in Android Studio.
I have included the jar in Dependencies.
Here it is what I see in gradle file after adding the jar in dependencies:
=> compile files('libs/com.symbol.amol.jar')

Application compiles fine.

But now if I add 'import com.symbol.amol' in the Activity.java file in the application, the error I get is => error: package com.symbol.amol does not exists.
Following is the image when I extract jar file.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the Project Properties -> App -> Dependencies and add your jar dependencies, this will do all instead of you

Comment: I already have added the jar to Open Module Settings -> app -> Dependencies.

Comment: Check if you package’s class are public and theire innered methods

Comment: Yes, Class is public and the method is static public.

Comment: You also have to put your jar library in libs directory

Comment: Yes, I alrady have copied jar file to /libs folder.